# Binding a mouse button click to anywhere on the Canvas, in Tcl Tk

Tags: canvas, tags, bind, tcl, tk-toolkit

I want my canvas to preform an action when a mouse button is clicked anywhere on the canvas area. I've been able to bind a click, but only when it's made on an existing object:

```
$this/zinc bind all <Button-1> [list select_shape $this]
```

I tried using the same command without specifying a tag:

```
$this/zinc bind <Button-1> [list select_shape $this]
```

It gave an error.

And by giving an empty string instead of a tag:

```
$this/zinc bind "" <Button-1> [list select_shape $this]
```

it acted as if I wrote `all`.

What `tag` do I give so that it'll work anywhere in the canvas, or how do I avoid specing a `tag`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The canvas's `bind` method only lets you bind to items (and tags applied to items) and then only for a subset of all Tk's events. If you want an event for the whole canvas — or to detect other types of events — use a global `bind` command:

```
bind $this/zinc <Button-1> {...}
```

Alternatively, put a fully transparent rectangle (both `-fill` and `-outline` set to the empty string) underneath all the other items and use that as a surface-of-last-resort. Like that, if nothing else picks up the click, that will. Or you could even put such a transparent item on top of everything (in which case it will intercept *all* mouse events) and do it that way. Note that rectangles (and polygons, for when you want non-rectangular hot areas) are special this way: most items are unresponsive in the parts of them you can't see, but fully-transparent rectangles are responsive over their whole area. This has *all sorts* of interesting uses.

(Sometimes you can combine the underlying rectangle with another item, e.g., a background image item.)

Comment: I don't know to what extent this advice also applies to the Zinc canvas-alike, but it's probably fairly good. The canvas event model is pretty sane, and also relatively well-known among Tk coders.